# Reproduce grep -Eo ".{0,20}error.{0,200}" ..\log\buildDeb.log in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to translate my batch file to python. Inside I use many command of Grep / Awk, ... So I attempt to reproduce that in Python, specifically the `"grep -Eo"` command with pattern like this `".{0,20}error.{0,200}"`.

I've just have some basic notion in python, I begin to write a script, with the re module  :

```
import os
import re

path_log = "C:/path/to/my/log/log"
os.chdir(path_log)
build_log = "buildDeb.log"
if os.path.exists(build_log):  # vérification du fichier de log
    log_file = open("buildDeb.log", "r+")
    pattern1 = "error C"
    for line in log_file:
        if re.search(pattern1, line):
            print(line)
            input()
```

That's working good, but not enough. I would, to begin, an **output** something like :

```
error C2491: 'ca::core::GetProcessDirectory' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
```

**or**

```
filepath.cpp(365) : error C2491: 'ca::core::GetProcessDirectory' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
```

For each line contains "error".

For information, my **buildDeb.log** is something like that :

```
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
core\src\filepath.cpp(365) : error C2491: 'ca::core::GetProcessDirectory' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
core\src\filepath.cpp(369) : error C2664: 'DWORD K32GetModuleFileNameExA(HANDLE,HMODULE,LPSTR,DWORD)' : cannot convert argument 3 from 'WCHAR [260]' to 'LPSTR'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
core\src\filepath.cpp(389) : error C2491: 'ca::core::GetCoreDirectory' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
core\src\filepath.cpp(393) : error C2664: 'DWORD GetModuleFileNameA(HMODULE,LPSTR,DWORD)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'WCHAR [260]' to 'LPSTR'
```

I've seen many example for just matching pattern, but not found for the matching after... or before.

1. Is the beginning of my code is good?
2. How can I have something like grep -Eo ".{0,20}error.{0,200}" in python ?
3. Can you please give me a little example to begin ?

I said that the goal is to have python code and preferably not use the module os.system if possible.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I have something like `grep -Eo ".{0,20}error.{0,200}"` in python ?

To print only the matched part, you need to use `group()` attribute in `re.search` method.

```
for line in log_file:
    m = re.search(r'.{0,20}error.{0,200}', line)
    if m:
        print(m.group())
```

**Output:**

```
filepath.cpp(365) : error C2491: 'ca::core::GetProcessDirectory' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
filepath.cpp(369) : error C2664: 'DWORD K32GetModuleFileNameExA(HANDLE,HMODULE,LPSTR,DWORD)' : cannot convert argument 3 from 'WCHAR [260]' to 'LPSTR'
filepath.cpp(389) : error C2491: 'ca::core::GetCoreDirectory' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
filepath.cpp(393) : error C2664: 'DWORD GetModuleFileNameA(HMODULE,LPSTR,DWORD)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'WCHAR [260]' to 'LPSTR'
```

Comment: But when I reproduced the same with something like that: `for line2 in log_file:
        p = re.search(r'.{0,20}cpp.', line2)
        if p:
            print(p.group())` just after, it doesn't work anymore.                        Is it normal ? I've to restart all the process ?

Comment: yep, once a line is readed then you need to add `seek()` to get back to the readed line. Still you have any further more doubts then ask it as a new question.